# do we have $n\mathbb{P}_X([n,+\infty[)\to 0 \quad as\quad n\to +\infty$?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory

Let X be a random variable.

I can't find a rigorous proof to show that

$n\mathbb{P}_X([n,+\infty[)\to 0 \quad as\quad n\to +\infty$

Comment: Do you know something more about $X$, most simply that the variance exists?

Comment: no it's just an arbitrary random variable !!

Comment: Then as you saw from the answer by Martini, the result need not hold. If the variance exists, the Chebyshev Inequality gives a positive answer. And one can get by with less.

Comment: yes but no inforamtion concerning the variance,but with the condition that martini adds it holds thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general we do not have this: If $P(X \ge n) \ge \frac 1n$ for every $n$, we have $nP_X([n, \infty)) \ge 1$. So if we have a random variable with 
$$ P(X = n) = \frac 1n - \frac 1{n+1} = \frac 1{n^2 + n}, \quad n \ge 1 $$
this is a counterexample, as for this $X$ $P(X \ge n) = \frac 1n$, all $n \in \mathbb N$.

Comment: yes you're right, it's a good counterexample, but I was wondering if we can find a condition to have the result in question ?

Comment: $X \in L^1(P)$ is sufficient, as in this case $$ nP(X \ge n) = \int_{X \ge n} n \, dP \le \int_{X \ge n} |X| \, dP \to 0$$

Comment: yes that makes a sense now, thank you.